# How to build Eloquent Query with related tables in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model

New to Laravel, I love it, it makes things a lot easier, but now I run into a challenge.

I have three tables: Profile, Registration and Profile__Registration.

```
Profile table columns: 
id (primary), user_id, firstname, lastname

Registration table columns: 
id (primary), reg_id, name

Profile__Registration table columns: 
id (primary), user_id, reg_id
```

So I use the last table to link a couple of different registrations to the user profiles.

I want to search the Profiles based on a combinations of Registrations. So for example I need to select the Profiles (user_id's) connected in the Profile__Registration table to all three reg_id's 2, 5 and 6 (so not user_id's that are connected to just 2 of them or less). But these connections are build trough different rows in the table, so a simple ::where() query doesn't do the trick.

Does anybody know how I can build an Eloquent Query to do this? I think on the Profile model?

I set up a hasManyThrough relation (cheers Artas!):

Profile.php

```
public function registrations()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\Registration',
        'App\Models\Profile_Registration',
        'user_id', 
        'reg_id', 
        'id', 
        'reg_id' 
    );
}
```

It works fine: $profile->registrations result in the connected Registrations.

But I did not yet succeeded in building a query on the Profile model such that I get back the Profiles that have Registration X and Registration Y..

I tried:

```
    $result = Profile::whereHas('registrations', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->whereIn('reg_id',[2,5,6]);
    })->get('user_id');
```

But I got error:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'reg_id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `user_id` from `profiles` where exists (select * from `registrations` inner join `profile__registrations` on `profile__registrations`.`reg_id` = `registrations`.`reg_id` where `profiles`.`id` = `profile__registrations`.`user_id` and `reg_id` in (2, 5, 6)))

Comment: You could use `hasManyThrough`relation [read here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: Do you have your relations set up?